# What does the symbol pipe '|' means in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, openwrt

From [target/linux/ar71xx/image/Makefile](https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/blob/master/target/linux/ar71xx/image/Makefile)

```
KERNEL := kernel-bin | patch-cmdline | lzma | uImage lzma
```

Could you please help me understand what does this line means and provide an example on how to use the symbol pipe `|` in a Makefile

Comment: From the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types

Comment: No, that's only true if the pipe symbol appears in a list of prerequisites.  Also, in that case there would only be one pipe symbol not 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is simply setting the make variable `KERNEL` to the string `kernel-bin | patch-cmdline | lzma | uImage lzma`.  The pipe symbol (`|`) has no special meaning to make here.

You'll have to see how the variable is being used.  Most likely it appears in a recipe somewhere, like this:

```
foo:
       $(KERNEL)
```

In that case the variable is expanded and the results are sent to the shell.  In the shell, the pipe symbol causes the stdout from the command on the lefto be hooked up to the stdin of the command on the righ: it's called a pipeline or piping data.

Here you have a pipeline of 4 comands: `kernel-bin`'s output is sent to `'patch-cmdline`'s input, `patch-cmdline`'s output is sent to `lzma`'s input, `lzma`'s output is sent to `uImage lzma`'s input.

Comment: Thx for the feedback, i think in this case it is not used to pass params between commands, i will post what i have understand

Comment: I didn't say "pass params", I said forward output to the next command's input.  Those are totally different things.  The makefile you linked to in your question isn't sufficient to answer your question.  It shows the variable is assigned inside a `define`'d variable, but that variable is never used within the makefile you provided.  You'll need to look elsewhere in the build system to see how it's used.  In particular look for the definition of the `BuildImage` variable which probably defines a recipe that uses the `KERNEL` variable.

Comment: Indeed, the makefile linked in the question is not very sufficient, this is why i have also added an answer to clarify how the pipe is used in my case.

Answer (score 6):

There is another use of '|' pipe symbol - to define order only prerequisites that simply provider target ordering and not build dependency:

For example:

```
OBJDIR := objdir
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,foo.o bar.o baz.o)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
        $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR):
        mkdir $(OBJDIR)
```

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html

Comment: Could you spell out what's being ordered?

Answer (score 1):

What is suggested by @MadScientist is very correct, but in this specific case i think that it is not used for passing parameters but rather for sequential calls of these command.

This is my understanding(correct me if wrong)

[This is where the variable is called](https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/blob/master/include/image.mk#L532): 
`$$(call concat_cmd,$$(KERNEL))`

1- `concat_cmd` will call `split_args` and pass the variable `KERNEL` and `build_cmd` to it:

```
define concat_cmd
$(call split_args,$(1),build_cmd)
endef
```

2- `split_args` will substitute the `|` with a space and call `build_cmd`,

```
define split_args
$(foreach data, \
$(subst |,$(space),\
    $(subst $(space),^,$(1))), \
$(call $(2),$(strip $(subst ^,$(space),$(data)))))
endef
```

3- Finally , because `KERNEL` is defined as `KERNEL := kernel-bin | patch-cmdline | lzma | uImage lzma`, `build_cmd` will expand to `Build/kernel-bin` `Build/ patch-cmdline` ...